# Python built from source can't find UTF-32-BE encoding

Tags: python, python-2.7, build, cpython, python-internals

I am working on a customized linux. When I used [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) to do some HTTP post, an import exception arised, something in [idna](https://pypi.org/project/idna/). One more sentence, my system is a little-endian linux.

```
>>> from uts46data import uts46data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
LookupError: unknown encoding: utf-32-be
>>>
```

I have checked the encoding as below.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'utf-8'
>>> sys.getfilesystemencoding()
'ANSI_X3.4-1968'
```

I guess this is an encoding issue, so what can I do?

More info as below.

```
/ # python -c "import sys;print(sys.version)"
2.7.8 (default, Jul  7 2020, 07:25:41) 
[GCC 7.3.1 20180425]
/ # python -c "import codecs;print codecs.lookup('utf-32-be')"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
LookupError: unknown encoding: utf-32-be
/ #
```

Comment: @snakecharmerbs Yes, I have to build python from source. The system is just like a emebedded system, build kernel, then add some applications.

Comment: I would check the `make` and `configure` output.  I would suspect that something that the codecs module requires to build utf-32-be was missing from the build environment.

Comment: It seems that utf-32-be.py is missing under the directory "Lib/encodings". Fixed.

Comment: @lxyscls if that's the solution, can you post and mark it as the Answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer myself.

Python will location it's encoding files from the encodings directory. You can copy the according encoding file from Python source package, under Lib/encodings directory.